# Logout Firebase doesn't really work

Tags: firebase, swift2, logout, firebase-authentication

I become crazy with a bug I have on my app. 
I use the new Firebase to authenticate a user + Firebase DB

2 ways to signup/signin: Email or Facebook.

In my App, I have a logout button with the simple command:

```
    try! FIRAUTH.auth()!.signOut()
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("firstScreen", sender: self)
```

works fine.

On a same iPhone, my test:

- Login with Facebook
- add datas to my app (firebase database)
- Log Out
- Login with an email account different of email used by Facebook

I retrieve the exact same datas that I had with my profile account. 
like if I wasn't really logged out.

I Have to kill the app after logout to have the datas corresponding to the account I use.

Do you have any idea ? 
What's happened exactly when I kill the app task ?

Thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I dealt with that same issue before, the problem is when you log out of firebase you also have to logout of facebook.

```
try! FIRAUTH.auth()!.signOut()
let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
loginManager.logOut()
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("firstScreen", sender: self)
```

If you don't you will keep getting the same data back when you log in.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Justin but unfortunately it's exactly the same issue with your solution.
Maybe I am wrong on my AppDelegate, where I check if the user is connected when he leaves the App:

```
//check if user has a currentUser ID
//if Yes, we check if he has a username
//if Yes, he goes to vc (first viewcontroller)
//if not, he geos to the vc2 where he chooses a username

if ((FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser) != nil){
userID = String(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid)
  ref.child("Users").child(userID).child("name").observeSingleEventOfType(FIRDataEventType.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        if (snapshot.value as? String == ""){
           self.window?.rootViewController = vc2
        }else{
           self.window?.rootViewController = vc
        }
    })   
}
```